# AWS EC2 instance access internal server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyramid

In my Amazon EC2 instance I have a Pyramid server as well as a NodeJS server running. The NodeJS server acts as the frontend and I updated my security groups so I can use the public DNS to view the page.

The Pyramid server acts as a backend and the frontend accesses it by `http://0.0.0.0:8002/`. But when I do an http call to the backend I get a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID` error message.

Do I need to add a rule to the security groups, or update the iptables, or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both of these services are running on the same server, you shouldn't be sending network traffic out of the server and back, so security groups will not be an issue here.

The question is, why are you using `0.0.0.0` here? I think you probably configured the Pyramid server to listen on `0.0.0.0`, which really means "listen on all IP addresses". However you need to be using `http://127.0.0.1:8002/` or `http://localhost:8002/` in order to connect to the service from another service running on the same server.

Comment: That makes sense...I updated the routes but I'm still getting the same error. However the source of the error has changed from `0.0.0.0:8002` to `angular.js:11442`. I'm viewing it in chrome.

Comment: Wait, if it is angular.js trying to access your Pyramid server then you will have to open that up to be accessible via internet browsers. AngularJS code runs in the browser, not the server. This is totally different from NodeJS trying to access this. If Angular is trying to access the server then you will have to open the port in the security group, and use the public IP address (or domain name) of the server.

Comment: I see, thank you. I already have the http port 80 open in AWS, and in my iptables I forward port 80 to the port angular is listening on. So do I need to forward port 80 to port 8002 as well?

Comment: Angular isn't listening on a port. Angular doesn't run on the server. I assume you mean you are forwarding port 80 to the port NodeJS is listening on. You can't forward port 80 to two different ports. Just open port 8002 in the security group and reference the server via http://public_ip_address:8002 in your AngularJS code.

Comment: Okay thanks Mark. The server stuff is new to me, don't know the terminology so well yet.